# Wrapping multi line labels

Tags: d3.js

I'm building a responsive zoomable treemap based on this [project](http://bl.ocks.org/ganeshv/6a8e9ada3ab7f2d88022). The problem is that the labels I've are longer than the original visualization and end up not showing:

```
function text(text) {
    text.selectAll("tspan")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) + 6; })
    text.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x) + 6; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y) + 6; })
        .style("opacity", function(d) { return this.getComputedTextLength() < x(d.x + d.dx) - x(d.x) ? 1 : 0; });
}
```

The problem I see is that the text needs to be showed completely in the first line, but I'd like to show it in multiple lines (inside the rect) instead.

There's a [code](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) by Mike Bostock which seems to solve this issue but I don't know how to apply it to the treemap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick a modification which wraps the parent text in that example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Generic treemap, based on http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/

-->
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Zoomable treemap template</title>
  <style>
    #chart {
      background: #fff;
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .title {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 24px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 6px;
      margin-bottom: 6px;
    }
    
    text {
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .grandparent text {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    rect {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #fff;
    }
    
    rect.parent,
    .grandparent rect {
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    
    rect.parent {
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .grandparent rect {
      fill: orange;
    }
    
    .grandparent:hover rect {
      fill: #ee9700;
    }
    
    .children rect.parent,
    .grandparent rect {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .children rect.parent {
      fill: #bbb;
      fill-opacity: .5;
    }
    
    .children:hover rect.child {
      fill: #bbb;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
      var opts = e.data.opts,
        data = e.data.data;

      return main(opts, data);
    });

    var defaults = {
      margin: {
        top: 24,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0
      },
      rootname: "TOP",
      format: ",d",
      title: "",
      width: 960,
      height: 500
    };

    function main(o, data) {
      var root,
        opts = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, o),
        formatNumber = d3.format(opts.format),
        rname = opts.rootname,
        margin = opts.margin,
        theight = 36 + 16;

      $('#chart').width(opts.width).height(opts.height);
      var width = opts.width - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = opts.height - margin.top - margin.bottom - theight,
        transitioning;

      var color = d3.scale.category20c();

      var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, width])
        .range([0, width]);

      var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, height])
        .range([0, height]);

      var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
        .children(function(d, depth) {
          return depth ? null : d._children;
        })
        .sort(function(a, b) {
          return a.value - b.value;
        })
        .ratio(height / width * 0.5 * (1 + Math.sqrt(5)))
        .round(false);

      var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
        .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
        .style("margin.right", -margin.right + "px")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");

      var grandparent = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "grandparent");

      grandparent.append("rect")
        .attr("y", -margin.top)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", margin.top);

      grandparent.append("text")
        .attr("x", 6)
        .attr("y", 6 - margin.top)
        .attr("dy", ".75em");

      if (opts.title) {
        $("#chart").prepend("<p class='title'>" + opts.title + "</p>");
      }
      if (data instanceof Array) {
        root = {
          key: rname,
          values: data
        };
      } else {
        root = data;
      }

      initialize(root);
      accumulate(root);
      layout(root);
      console.log(root);
      display(root);

      if (window.parent !== window) {
        var myheight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight || document.body.scrollHeight;
        window.parent.postMessage({
          height: myheight
        }, '*');
      }

      function initialize(root) {
        root.x = root.y = 0;
        root.dx = width;
        root.dy = height;
        root.depth = 0;
      }

      // Aggregate the values for internal nodes. This is normally done by the
      // treemap layout, but not here because of our custom implementation.
      // We also take a snapshot of the original children (_children) to avoid
      // the children being overwritten when when layout is computed.
      function accumulate(d) {
        return (d._children = d.values) ? d.value = d.values.reduce(function(p, v) {
          return p + accumulate(v);
        }, 0) : d.value;
      }

      // Compute the treemap layout recursively such that each group of siblings
      // uses the same size (1×1) rather than the dimensions of the parent cell.
      // This optimizes the layout for the current zoom state. Note that a wrapper
      // object is created for the parent node for each group of siblings so that
      // the parent’s dimensions are not discarded as we recurse. Since each group
      // of sibling was laid out in 1×1, we must rescale to fit using absolute
      // coordinates. This lets us use a viewport to zoom.
      function layout(d) {
        if (d._children) {
          treemap.nodes({
            _children: d._children
          });
          d._children.forEach(function(c) {
            c.x = d.x + c.x * d.dx;
            c.y = d.y + c.y * d.dy;
            c.dx *= d.dx;
            c.dy *= d.dy;
            c.parent = d;
            layout(c);
          });
        }
      }

      function display(d) {
        grandparent
          .datum(d.parent)
          .on("click", transition)
          .select("text")
          .text(name(d));

        var g1 = svg.insert("g", ".grandparent")
          .datum(d)
          .attr("class", "depth");

        var g = g1.selectAll("g")
          .data(d._children)
          .enter().append("g");

        g.filter(function(d) {
            return d._children;
          })
          .classed("children", true)
          .on("click", transition);

        var children = g.selectAll(".child")
          .data(function(d) {
            return d._children || [d];
          })
          .enter().append("g");

        children.append("rect")
          .attr("class", "child")
          .call(rect)
          .append("title")
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.key + " (" + formatNumber(d.value) + ")";
          });
        children.append("text")
          .attr("class", "ctext")
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.key;
          })
          .call(text2);

        g.append("rect")
          .attr("class", "parent")
          .call(rect);

        var t = g.append("text")
          .attr("class", "ptext")
          .attr("dy", ".75em")

        t.append("tspan")
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.key;
          });
        t.append("tspan")
          .attr("dy", "1.0em")
          .text(function(d) {
            return formatNumber(d.value);
          });
        t.call(text);

        g.selectAll("rect")
          .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.key);
          });

        function transition(d) {
          if (transitioning || !d) return;
          transitioning = true;

          var g2 = display(d),
            t1 = g1.transition().duration(750),
            t2 = g2.transition().duration(750);

          // Update the domain only after entering new elements.
          x.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
          y.domain([d.y, d.y + d.dy]);

          // Enable anti-aliasing during the transition.
          svg.style("shape-rendering", null);

          // Draw child nodes on top of parent nodes.
          svg.selectAll(".depth").sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.depth - b.depth;
          });

          // Fade-in entering text.
          g2.selectAll("text").style("fill-opacity", 0);

          // Transition to the new view.
          t1.selectAll(".ptext").call(text).style("fill-opacity", 0);
          t1.selectAll(".ctext").call(text2).style("fill-opacity", 0);
          t2.selectAll(".ptext").call(text).style("fill-opacity", 1);
          t2.selectAll(".ctext").call(text2).style("fill-opacity", 1);
          t1.selectAll("rect").call(rect);
          t2.selectAll("rect").call(rect);

          // Remove the old node when the transition is finished.
          t1.remove().each("end", function() {
            svg.style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
            transitioning = false;
          });
        }

        return g;
      }

      function text(text) {
        text.selectAll("tspan")
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.x) + 6;
          })
        text.attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.x) + 6;
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.y) + 6;
          })
          .each(function(d) {
            var tspan = this.childNodes[0];
            var w = x(d.x + d.dx) - x(d.x);
            wrap(tspan, w, x(d.x) + 6);
          })
      }

      function text2(text) {
        text.attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.x + d.dx) - this.getComputedTextLength() - 6;
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.y + d.dy) - 6;
          })
          .style("opacity", function(d) {
            return this.getComputedTextLength() < x(d.x + d.dx) - x(d.x) ? 1 : 0;
          });
      }

      function rect(rect) {
        rect.attr("x", function(d) {
            return x(d.x);
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.y);
          })
          .attr("width", function(d) {
            return x(d.x + d.dx) - x(d.x);
          })
          .attr("height", function(d) {
            return y(d.y + d.dy) - y(d.y);
          });
      }

      function name(d) {
        return d.parent ? name(d.parent) + " / " + d.key + " (" + formatNumber(d.value) + ")" : d.key + " (" + formatNumber(d.value) + ")";
      }
    }

    if (window.location.hash === "") {
      d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/7c30e101-da91-11e6-90ab-11c211a4b3d5", function(err, res) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log(res);
          var data = d3.nest().key(function(d) {
            return d.region;
          }).key(function(d) {
            return d.subregion;
          }).entries(res);
          main({
            title: "World Population"
          }, {
            key: "World",
            values: data
          });
        }
      });
    }

    function wrap(tspan, width, x) {
      
      var text = d3.select(tspan), 
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")) || 0.4,
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", "0.75em");
        
      while (word = words.pop()) {
        line.push(word);
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
          line.pop();
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          line = [word];
          tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y).attr("dy", "1em").text(word);
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```